# Cloud function trigger for multiple collections which start with a same text

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I know one can add a trigger to all the documents of a particular collection like

```
functions.firestore.document('Subscriber/{userID}').onCreate((snap, context)
```

But I have multiple collections like Subscriber1, Subscriber2, Subscriber3 and so on. 
Is there a way to write a trigger when any change happens to any collection which starts with Subscriber. Something like

```
functions.firestore.document('Subscriber**/{userID}').onCreate((snap, context)
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no regular expressions or substring matches in Cloud Functions triggers.  You need to either **specify the full name of the collection** to trigger on, or **wildcard the entire collection name**.  You can always check the name of the collection in the trigger code to see if it matches a pattern you expect, then return early if it's not.

Top-level collection names with highly variable values are usually a symptom of database design that's working against the way Firestore was intended to be used.

Answer (score 3):

I settled on exporting various cloud functions in my index.ts file, all of which listen for events in different collections but then delegate to the same function.

```
export const onSubscriberOneDocumentCreated = functions.firestore.document('/Subscriber1/{id}').onCreate(onSubscriberDocCreated);

export const onSubscriberTwoDocumentCreated = functions.firestore.document('/Subscriber2/{id}').onCreate(onSubscriberDocCreated);

export const onSubscriberThreeDocumentCreated = functions.firestore.document('/Subscriber3/{id}').onCreate(onSubscriberDocCreated);

async function onSubscriberDocCreated(snapshot: functions.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
    // Add logic you want to perform when a document is created in the Subscriber1, Subscriber2 or Subscriber3 collection here
}
```

Comment: Seems to be the only solution as of now. They should probably do a "group collection" type of way of referencing the collection.